# Confused about nested object literal properties

Tags: javascript, canvas

While I was reading some Javascript source-code ([here](http://pmav.eu/stuff/javascript-game-of-life-v3.1.1/)) of a [Conway's Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life), I stumbled upon something that I've never seen before (well, I started out with Javascript three weeks ago. For sake of context, I'm coming from a C++ background and I'm using [Professional JavaScript for Web Developers](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-JavaScript-for-Web-Developers-3rd-Edition.productCd-1118222199.html) as a guide to try to understand JS)

This is the situation ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5jDd/)):

```
var Obj = {
    canvas: {
        context : null,
        init : function() {
            this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            this.canvas.width = 50;
            this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
            /* ... */
        }
    }
}

Obj.canvas.init();
```

I do understand that this is an object literal with nested object literal properties. What I don't understand is the  `this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');` part. I thought I'd need to declare a variable, such as `context` is declared above, to get the canvas element.

This obviously works, as stated on the fiddle, however, what is going on? More precisely, by making canvas a HTML element object, why am I not losing all of it's other properties, such as `context`?

Comment: @Alexander `this` inside `Obj.canvas.init()` points to `Obj.canvas`, not `Obj`

Comment: @Tibos Oh, right, I didn't noticed that nested inside canvas{}. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two different objects called "canvas" here. One is the member of `Obj` and another is the member of `Obj.canvas`. `Obj.canvas` is a generic object, and `Obj.canvas.canvas` is a HTML element. You can see that when you add `console.dir(Obj)` after the "init" line.

Whether it's a good practice to name things like this is another question. I'd rather write it like this:

```
var Obj = {
    canvas: {
        context : null,
        element: null,
        init : function() {
            this.element = document.getElementById('canvas');
            this.element.width = 50;
            this.context = this.element.getContext('2d');
            etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

Kinda confusing pattern. With same name `canvas` are named 4 different things: Object Property, HTML element, Method and ID of element.

Maybe this sample can also helps you to understand to architecture and naming conventions:

http://jsfiddle.net/ondrek/FLPmL/

**Javascript:**

```
var workingWithCanvas = {

    _canvasVariable : document.getElementById('IDcanvas'),

    init : function () {
        this._canvasVariable.width = 500;
        this._canvasVariable.context = this._canvasVariable.getContext('2d');
    },

    changeWidth : function (newWidth) {
        this._canvasVariable.width = newWidth;
    }

}; 

workingWithCanvas.init();
workingWithCanvas.changeWidth(10);
```

**HTML:**

```
<canvas id="IDcanvas"></canvas>
```

Btw. Just hint and best practise (i know that its not your code): Don't name variables like `Obj`, `Object`, `Canvas` :-)